# How to display Array of Objects using fb_graph in a Rails Application

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rubygems

I am a Rails Newbie.

I am using fb_graph gem to extract information. Rails 3.2.1 & Ruby 1.9.2p290

In my controller I have

```
@user_facebook = FbGraph::User.fetch('my.Name', :access_token => 'myaccesstoken')
```

In my view, I have

```
<%= @user_facebook.name %><br/>
<%= @user_facebook.identifier %><br/>
<%= @user_facebook.picture %><br/>
<%= @user_facebook.link %><br/>
<%= @user_facebook.username %><br/>
<%= @user_facebook.bio %><br/>
<%= @user_facebook.birthday %><br/>
```

The Output is displayed as it is intended but..

for `<%= @user_facebook.education %>` I get the entire array of objects as the facebook document says..

```
[#<FbGraph::Education:0x007f950bc0a088 @school=#<FbGraph::Page:0x007f950bc09d90 @identifier="134788803212663", @endpoint="https://graph.facebook.com/134788803212663", @access_token=nil, @cached_collections={}, **@name="abcdefghijkl"**, @username=nil, @category=nil, @talking_about_count=nil, @like_count=nil, @affiliation=nil, @artists_we_like=nil, @attire=nil, @awards=nil, @band_interests=nil, @band_members=nil, @bio=nil, @booking_agent=nil, @can_post=nil, @company_overview=nil, @culinary_team=nil ............. ..... ........ ....@founded=nil, @release_date=nil, @checkin_count=nil, @hours={}>>]
```

When I use this <%= @user_facebook.education.first %>

i get `#<FbGraph::Education:0x007f950f47c330>`

and

When I use this `<%= @user_facebook.education.last %>`

i get `#<FbGraph::Education:0x007f950e4e1790>`

How can I get a simple list of all the schools I went.. [its in @name] but I not sure, who to extract just that information.

Looking for help and support! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my reading of the [code](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/blob/master/lib/fb_graph/education.rb) for FbGraph::Education it should be `@user_facebook.education[0].school`. It is an object with attrs to access for information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it results in an error! It says undefined method `school' for #<Array:0x007f950e4ff790>

Comment: @reko Looking into it... my apologies

Comment: @reko I forgot that it was in an array. Does using the `[0]` change anything?